# Object under cursor not found

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs, mouseclick-event

I tried three different approaches but none worked.

I place two rectangles on the canvas and want to catch the object under the mouse cursor when a mousedown event occurred.

The stagemousedown works, but the objects are not found. Watching the debugger I see that the rectangle has still the drawrect coordinates, not the one that I set later. There is also a 'hitarea' which I don't know how to use since it is checked during hittest and getObjectUnderPoint.

Approach 1: makeButton creates a handler on lines 66ff -> it never fires

Approach 2: getObjectUnderPoint when a mousedown evt happens. -> returns always null

Approach 3: loop through each child and apply the hitttest -> returns always false.

I come from Java and C# and am far from being experienced in JS, but I had hoped that I could catch the mousedown with at least one approach.

What makes me wonder is that the x and y in the rectangle never change from the ones used during creation (0,0). That's not the current position which I set for example in 73 and 74!

I don't seem to find the REAL x and y of the object and neither does approaches 2 and 3. I wished, approach 1 would work since that makes the most sense to me.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EaselJS/1.0.2/easeljs.js"></script>
    <script>

    function init() {
        var followme = 0;
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var stage=new createjs.Stage(canvas);
        var shape=new createjs.Shape();
        var dispO = new createjs.Shape();

        makeBtn(3,3);
        makeBtn(300,300);
        stage.on("stagemousedown", function (evt) {
            followme = 1;
            found=stage.getObjectUnderPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY,0)
            if(found != null)
            {
                console.log(found);
            }
            var xxx=stage.children;
            for (i=0; i<xxx.length;i++)
            {
                if (xxx[i].hitTest(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY))
                {
                    shape.alpha=1;
                }
            }
        });
        stage.on("stagemouseup", function (evt) {
            followme = 0;
        });
        stage.update();

        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
        function handleTick(event) 
        {
            if ((followme === 1) && (dispO != null))
            {
                var difX = stage.mouseX - dispO.x - 100;
                var difY = stage.mouseY - dispO.y - 50;

                dispO.x += difX / 20;
                dispO.y += difY / 20;
                stage.update();
            }
            else
            if(dispO != null)
            {
                var dmy=dispO;
            }
        }
        function makeBtn(x,y)
        {
                shape = new createjs.Shape();
                shape.graphics.beginStroke("black").setStrokeStyle(2, 0, 1).drawRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
                dispO=shape;
                dispO.mouseEventsEnabled = true;
                var handler=dispO.on("mousedown", 
                    function(event) {console.log(instance == this); },// true, "on" uses dispatcher scope by default.      
                    null,
                    once=true,
                    'theButton',
                    useCapture=true
                );
                dispO.x=x;
                dispO.y=y;
                stage.addChild(dispO);
                
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div id="outer">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="600">
        </canvas>
            <menu id="controls">
            </menu>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EaselJS/1.0.2/easeljs.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your demo works fine -- its just that your square has no fill, so only the border is clickable. If you add a fill, then it works great:

https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ozcr6tna/

```
shape.graphics.beginStroke("black")
  .setStrokeStyle(2, 0, 1)
  .beginFill("white") //      <----- Fill call
  .drawRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
```

If you want the clickable area to be transparent, then you can use a hitArea. Just assign a different shape with a fill as a hitArea (and don't add that shape to the stage). Hit testing in EaselJS uses pixel fill - so if there are no pixels, then there is no hit!

Hope that helps!